# Change CSS attribute value present in two different rules by adding a class

Tags: javascript, css

I'm adding a class to a div in order to momentarily change its border color.
But it already has a CSS rule setting its border color.

I'm guessing that is why it doesn't change.
How could I achieve that?

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player');
player.classList.add('playing');
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.playing {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted should work, so something else is preventing the border color from changing. Please include more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have the div in the HTML code? Did you query it correctly to assign to the `div` variable? Here seems to be the "just working" code.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
div.classList.add('playing');
```

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    width: 100px; height: 200px;
}

.playing {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will solve your problem.Probably you couldn't catch your div element so you had problem during your trying.

```
    <style>
        div{
        border: 5px solid grey;
        }
        .playing{
        border-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>

    <div>Test</div>

    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList.add("playing");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**Note:** This is valid for the extreme case that there is only one div on the screen or that it is the first inside the body. Fore more flexibility you can add an `id` to the div element and then replace `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];` with `document.getElementById('idOfDiv');` below.

```js
function startPlaying() {
  div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  div.classList.add('playing');
}

function stopPlaying() {
  div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  div.classList.remove('playing');
}
```

```css
div{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    padding:20px
}

.playing{
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<input type="button" value="Start playing" onclick="startPlaying()" />
<input type="button" value="Stop playing" onclick="stopPlaying()" />
```